# Error when using Grid from Kendo together with AngularJS (also using angular-kendo)

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've probably done a silly mistake, but I'm unable to understand why I get this error, or how I can resolve it (or even if it's something I should resolve...)

Anyway I've made a plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/pTMgRq33iWBiiBY4apTr?p=preview

### Problem explained:

- Using: JQuery, AngularJS, KendoUI and angular-kendo.
- Have two Angular views, one with a KendoUI grid.
- When navigating away from the view containing the grid, I get this error:

  - Cannot call method 'destroy' of kendoDropTarget before it is initialized

Hoping for anyone understanding this, and able to explain it to me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is being tracked in the Angular-Kendo github project as a bug:
https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo/issues/66

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes.  This was indeed a bug in KendoUI on the grids and was fixed with their 2013.3.1119 release.